# What alternative to php_sapi_name() is good for Google App Engine?

Tags: php

How can I determine whether a script is running from CLI or CGI (inc. Google App Engine), without using php_sapi_name()?

EDIT: Without relying on undefined behaviour.

Google App Engine says:

```
 php_sapi_name() has been disabled for security reasons
```

and though I can re-enable it in php.ini, I would prefer not, esp. since I can't find the security reasons stated.

EDIT: if(isset($argv[1])) appears to work, but relies on undefined behaviour of $argv in CGI. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php .

Comment: There is also the `PHP_SAPI` constant which contains the same value.

Comment: Thanks, but unlike php_sapi_name()'s, PHP_SAPI's behaviour is undefined, despite the implication of http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Comment: How about making three scripts, one that does the actual work and two that each define an entry point , one for cli one for web? The latter two would "collect" the input and then invoke the first script accordingly. You might even (if necessary) define a constant in the entry scripts.

Comment: VolkerK Thanks. That's the current solution which I am looking to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `$_SERVER` superglobal Variable for one of the following values:

- REQUEST_METHOD
- SERVER_ADDR
- SERVER_SOFTWARE
- SERVER_NAME

like this:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'])) {
     echo 'this is run on the cli';
}
```

If you want to check for the google-app engine try `$_SERVER['APPLICATION_ID'];` according to their docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Special_server_keys

Comment: Thanks, but that's unsafe since any could appear in CLI. That array holds the OS environment variables here on Windows.